# Go to PHP site in background

Tags: java, android

I have a PHP site on a Raspberry Pi and would like my Android application to simply go to this site when I click a button and run the code. The code opens a garage door with a relay.

How would I code 'onclick' to go to this PHP site in the background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a very simple implementation:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                try {
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    conn.connect();
                } finally {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }

            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If you want to do more (such as handling a response from the webpage), read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).